# Convert an object to a date

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have imported an xml file that contains a date stamp. I extracted the date stamp by placing it into an Object:

```
dataObject = new Object();
dataObject.date = ... etc.
```

The date stamp was created by a sql database and its structure is as follows, but it is no longer a Date:

```
 2011-02-03 16:30:10
```

Can I convert the text in the Object back into a Date object within Flex to be able to use Date methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Date::parse` for this:

```
var date:Date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
```

However, note that Flash doesn't recognize "-" as a separator so you need to convert the string first. Something like this should work:

```
dateString = dateString.replace(new RegExp(/-/g), '/');
var date:Date = Date.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: This gave me the following error: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type Date. Here's what I wrote:     trace("Start="+dataObject.date)
    var dateString:String = String(dataObject.date)
    trace("Next0="+dateString)
    dateString = dateString.replace('-', '/');
    trace("Next1="+dateString)
    dateString = dateString.replace('-', '/');
    trace("Next2="+dateString)
    
    var date:Date = Date.parse(dateString);

Comment: @user1209902, I've updated my answer - it should be `new Date(Date.parse(dateString))`